# Any one used Sonarqube to review loadrunner scripts?

Tags: jmeter, continuous-integration, sonarqube, loadrunner, github-codereviews

I would like to use Sonarqube to review LoadRunner/Jmeter scripts to check the code quality, are followed standards and best practice during test design.
any one used Sonarqube to do that before?

Comment: Which protocol?

Answer (score 0):

You could evaluate against coding standards pretty easily, such as inclusion of comments, standards for variable naming, etc...   But who are you going to get to write the rules to determine if the script is valid, whether the items which are dynamic and need to be addressed, have been, whether you are checking for valid expected results?